# How to access localhost of usb connected PC

Tags: android

I recently installed the adb for google's chrome in order to debug a webpage on my nexus 4 phone. 
The page is running on localhost:8080 of my PC(tomcat server).
In chrome(PC).I can see the connected phone and I am able to send reload command, apparently the connection is working fine.
The problem is that I am not able to open the localhost of my PC from my nexus phone.
I tried to open 10.0.0.2 as well without success.
So how is it possible to connect to localhost?

Comment: Try 10.0.2.2 instead. You'll find more info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias

Comment: @NKN - no, 10.0.2.2 **is only for emulators** not devices.

Comment: You cannot, by definition, access the "localhost" of your PC from any machine other than the PC itself, as then it would not be the Local Host, but some Remote machine.  Android does not support any out-of-the-box scheme *intended* for accessing a PC over the ADB connection, though you may be able to do so using a common wifi network or as a *side effect* of some types of tethering.  Ultimately, this question should be closed as it is a duplicate of many previous ones on the same topic.

Comment: @ChrisStratton true, I think I read the question too fast... Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

@nkn
10.0.2.2 is only for emulators not devices.

you are right.
Opening localhost:8080 on the phone worked out with port forwarding enabled on the pc.